# Complex raw queries in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have a fairly complex query with six left joins, and I'm trying to build a raw query in laravel to get my result.

Would be nice if I could just paste my query into the code, but even using the raw expressions, I still have to separate out the select keywords from the where keywords, etc.

Is there no way to use a 100% raw query?

Comment: maybe interesting? http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

Comment: Looks promising... I'll give it a go